# How to do 3-legged OAuth login with One Tap sign-in on Android

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity, google-one-tap

I'm trying to implement 3-legged OAuth login with Google's [One Tap sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android) for Android. This is needed to access Gmail from the **server side**.

The app needs to get a **server auth code** and pass it to the server which stores it. The server will later exchange it for a refresh token and access token and use it to pull email.

I use the following code (error checking removed for brevity) which gets me a token, but it's NOT a refresh token. What I need is a **server auth code** that I can exchange for access and **refresh** tokens like.

```
// Show the one tap sign in account selector
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>(List.of("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            ..., ... // other scopes come here
));
BeginSignInRequest signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
        .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                .associateLinkedAccounts(LINKED_SERVICE, scopes) // what is this LINKED_SERVICE?
                .setSupported(true)
                .setServerClientId(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .build())
        .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
        .build();
SignInClient oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(activity);
oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<BeginSignInResult> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful())
            return;
        BeginSignInResult signInResult = task.getResult();
        PendingIntent signInIntent = signInResult.getPendingIntent();
        activity.startIntentSenderForResult(signInIntent.getIntentSender(), REQ_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0));
    }
});
```

Then in the intent receiver:

```
// Handle response from the one tap account selector
public void onResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Assume requestCode==REQ_SIGN_IN and resultCode is OK (for brevity)
    SignInCredential cred = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data);
    String idTokenString = cred.getGoogleIdToken();
    // Now what? This is an Oauth token for client-side use.
    // How to I get a server auth code that can be exchanged for a refresh and access tokens at the server-side?
}
```

Is there a way to get the server auth code?

**Comment**:
Until now I was using the GoogleSignIn API in the following manner, but it's being phased out and not sure when it's going to stop working (documentation states March 31, 2023).

```
// Start the OAuth sign in
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"), new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"))
    .requestServerAuthCode(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
Intent intent = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso).getSignInIntent();
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_SIGN_IN);
```

The result is returned to the activity (again, no error checking)

```
public void onResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = task.getResult();
    String authCode = acct.getServerAuthCode(); // Server will exchange this for access and refresh tokens
    // Pass this authCode to the server
}
```

Answer (score 1):

New Google Sign-In API using `Identity.getSignInClient(activity)` doesn't support 3-legged OAuth.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity) states:

> For new apps we recommend using Google Identity Services instead of the
> Google Sign-In API for sign-in and sign-up, **unless you need**
> authorization, [**Server-Side Access**](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) (!!!), or custom OAuth scopes.

Old Google Sign-in is scheduled to be deprecated at March 31, 2023. However, until now (September 2022) there is no sign that the new API will add support.

Answer (score -1):

Linked account sign-in uses access and refresh tokens issued by another, non-Google partner site or platform. Data is shared from the partner platform TO Google using OAuth2. In this scenario the partner platform defines the scope names, and Google requests and requests and manages the access and refresh tokens issued by the partner platform -- your app does not manage the
credentials. An example of this might be playing music or video managed by a different company on a Google Home hub.

From your comments it sounds like you are looking to request Google [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) and work with Google Account user data?   In your example code, you are using authentication scopes only (email, profile) and simply using [One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials) to obtain an ID token would be the most straightforward. Should you need to work with Google scopes, for Android you'll currently need to use the older [Google Sign-in APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/additional-scopes).  Somewhat confusingly, the sign-in options for user authentication are using newer Android API's while authorization to work with Google Account user data remains on the older Google Sign-in APIs.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I need a Google refresh token to access gmail (there are other scopes that I didn't list). The older Google sign-in that I previously used stopped working some time ago.

Comment: On Android you'll need to follow the instructions in the last link in my reply.

Comment: I was previously using GoogleSignIn, as I wrote in my question (with example), but it stopped working. The oauth page appeared, but when I press the allow button, it goes back to the account selector and starts all over again (it doesn't return the token). My code used to work, but something got obsoleted.

Comment: Could you share the resultCode you're seeing returned to onActivityResult ?

Comment: resultCode is Activity.RESULT_OK - I wrote in the code that it doesn't include error checking, but there is error checking in the full code. It all goes fine, but GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent returns a task with getGoogleIdToken() that is NOT a refresh token.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. [IdToken](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getIdToken()) is returned to your mobile app. It contains the JWT with user profile info. The refresh token is obtained using a request made from your backend platform. All the Android app does is to send an authorization code obtained from getServerAuthCode() to the backend.  The refresh and access tokens are obtained there. Google refers to this process as the "offline" flow.

Comment: See, [step 7](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_7_exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token) which is common to both web and mobile apps (Android/iOS) for how to exchange the auth code for refresh and access tokens.

Comment: Step 7 requires the google api server side sdk which I cannot use from technical reasons. In the past, we used to call https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with the code, client id and server secret and with grant_type=authorization_code. Is there a documentation of the new method with direct REST APIs?

Comment: you are missing the point. My question is about 3-leg oauth! I need to get a refresh token that the server will later exchange for access token. The oauth2.googleapis.com/token endpoint from step 7 returns an access token which is not what I need.

Comment: getServerAuthCode()  is used to implement three-legged OAuth. The authorization code returned to your Android app is sent to your backend where it is exchanged for refresh and access tokens.

Comment: I think you don't understand the problem. I suggest you read my question again - it's all explained there. What you say is not true. GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso).getSignInIntent() doesn't work anymore - it does an endless loop and doesn't return. Also, I tried to exchange the code I get from oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data).getGoogleIdToken() using https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token and it failed. So no, the new one tap SDK doesn't support 3-leg.

Comment: You're right I don't. The comments here do not match up with the question or code sample anymore. The conversation has switched topics.

Comment: Please post an updated question and/or code sample.  Also if I was you I would double check that the OAuth Client ID application types being used are Android and Web application for your mobile app and backend platform auth code endpoint respectively. The last comment you made may indicate those are crossed.